# How is REQUEST object for a user in Django Views diffrentiated from one to another?

Tags: django, django-views, django-messages, django-request

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right or wrong. But this functionality brought me across a very esoteric event happening inside Django Views.

So the code:

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages
from django.contrib import messages
#Other required modules.

@require_GET
def get_form(request):
    #code to get a form.
    storage = get_messages(request)
    for message in storage:
        message = message
    if message:
        context['message'] = message
    html = render(request , 'some_html.html' , context)
    return HttpResponse(html)

@require_POST
def submit_form(request):
    #Initialize a bounded form.
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, success_message)
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, error_message)    
        # ABOVE LINE IS WHERE THE ISSUE OCCURS
        return redirect('reverse_url_mapping_to_get_form') 
        # Above line is redirecting to "get_form" function(The function preceding this one).
```

**ISSUE** : Now the strange thing I encountered occurred when I made a typo in `return redirect('reverse_url_mapping_to_get_form')`(The last line of the code mentioned.).

Obviously I encountered Django's error page, saying that there is "NoReverseMatch". **But** when I reloaded the form(normal refreshing through the browser, on the "url" mapping to `get_form(request)`), I found that the error message which I added in the line `messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, error_message)` was being brought to the html(some_html.html). Even thought the error occurred and I never redirected to the url successfully.

Now I understand that `messages.add_message()` somewhat piggybacks on the request, **BUT**, shouldn't it have been destroyed in the case when error occurred. The case where the redirect wasn't successfully executed.

Why did the message was still inside the **request object** when the reload occur?

Shouldn't it have been destroyed(because it was a completely independent GET request; I initiated it from my browser by reloading)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've completely misunderstood how the messages framework works. It does not store the messages in the request; they are stored in the session.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Just wanted to ask that if a message is not extracted in views for a request hit to the server from `get_messages(request)` by any chance, then is it likely that it'll be extracted the next time when the user's request hit to the server comes across `get_messages(request)` even if the message wasn't meant for that particular request hit to the server?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Once added, messages persist until they are displayed. This is fully explained in the documentation.

Comment: Apologies for the confusing question. I wanted to know that messages persist or not. Apart from this, I found what I was looking for in the documentation. Thanks a lot again.